# On CR303000 page Contact tab selects all data not top

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that on CR303000 page contact tab selects all records not top, what should be the reason?

I used Request Profiler to see generated SQL text.

Answer (score 0):

The reason should be Paging, when you set AllowPaging property to False the request will not limit the number of results using the SQL Top statement.

I couldn't replicate your result with Acumatica 6.1.x default deployment.

When setting AllowPaging = False in a customization for that grid, I do replicate your result:
[image: AllowPaging]